# How to make Wildfly 11 server available during deployment?

Tags: wildfly

We have an EAR with multiple WARs (web services). Those WARs talk to each other during deployment phase using Wildfly's HTTP server. We are using 8.2.0, 10.0.0 and 10.1.0 without problems right now, but we'd like to upgrade to newer Wildfly. I noticed that HTTP server from Wildfly 11 on (I tested until Wldfly 20) is not responding during deployment phase if EAR is in deployment folder when server is started. However, if server is started first and then I put EAR in deployment folder, HTTP server is responding and EAR is deployed correctly.

Is is possible to change this behaviour, so that HTTP server would respond to requests during deployment phase also when server is started with EAR placed in deployments folder?

Relevant logs of Wildfly 11 (notice `Resuming server`):

```
wildfly2_1  | 08:37:14,606 INFO  [org.jboss.as.server.deployment.scanner] (MSC service thread 1-3) WFLYDS0013: Started FileSystemDeploymentService for directory /wildfly/wildfly-11.0.0.Final/standalone/deployments
wildfly2_1  | 08:37:14,610 INFO  [org.jboss.as.server.deployment] (MSC service thread 1-7) WFLYSRV0027: Starting deployment of "ojdbc7.jar" (runtime-name: "ojdbc7.jar")
wildfly2_1  | 08:37:14,610 INFO  [org.jboss.as.server.deployment] (MSC service thread 1-6) WFLYSRV0027: Starting deployment of "mysql-connector-java-5.1.6.jar" (runtime-name: "mysql-connector-java-5.1.6.jar")
wildfly2_1  | 08:37:14,610 INFO  [org.jboss.as.server.deployment] (MSC service thread 1-2) WFLYSRV0027: Starting deployment of "sqljdbc4.jar" (runtime-name: "sqljdbc4.jar")
wildfly2_1  | 08:37:14,946 INFO  [org.wildfly.extension.undertow] (MSC service thread 1-8) WFLYUT0006: Undertow HTTPS listener https listening on 10.100.1.131:8443
wildfly2_1  | 08:37:15,052 INFO  [org.jboss.ws.common.management] (MSC service thread 1-5) JBWS022052: Starting JBossWS 5.1.9.Final (Apache CXF 3.1.12)
wildfly2_1  | 08:37:15,435 INFO  [org.jboss.as.connector.deployers.jdbc] (MSC service thread 1-7) WFLYJCA0005: Deploying non-JDBC-compliant driver class com.mysql.jdbc.Driver (version 5.1)
wildfly2_1  | 08:37:15,460 INFO  [org.jboss.as.connector.deployers.jdbc] (MSC service thread 1-3) WFLYJCA0004: Deploying JDBC-compliant driver class com.microsoft.sqlserver.jdbc.SQLServerDriver (version 4.0)
wildfly2_1  | 08:37:15,477 INFO  [org.jboss.as.connector.deployers.jdbc] (MSC service thread 1-8) WFLYJCA0004: Deploying JDBC-compliant driver class oracle.jdbc.OracleDriver (version 12.1)
wildfly2_1  | 08:37:15,533 INFO  [org.jboss.as.connector.deployers.jdbc] (MSC service thread 1-7) WFLYJCA0018: Started Driver service with driver-name = sqljdbc4.jar
wildfly2_1  | 08:37:15,536 INFO  [org.jboss.as.connector.deployers.jdbc] (MSC service thread 1-4) WFLYJCA0018: Started Driver service with driver-name = mysql-connector-java-5.1.6.jar
wildfly2_1  | 08:37:15,543 INFO  [org.jboss.as.connector.deployers.jdbc] (MSC service thread 1-6) WFLYJCA0018: Started Driver service with driver-name = ojdbc7.jar
wildfly2_1  | 08:37:15,546 INFO  [org.jboss.as.connector.subsystems.datasources] (MSC service thread 1-4) WFLYJCA0098: Bound non-transactional data source: java:/jdbc/ShakeSpeare
wildfly2_1  | 08:37:15,732 INFO  [org.infinispan.factories.GlobalComponentRegistry] (MSC service thread 1-3) ISPN000128: Infinispan version: Infinispan 'Chakra' 8.2.8.Final
wildfly2_1  | 08:37:16,027 INFO  [org.jboss.as.clustering.infinispan] (ServerService Thread Pool -- 62) WFLYCLINF0002: Started client-mappings cache from ejb container
wildfly2_1  | 08:37:16,122 INFO  [org.jboss.as.server] (ServerService Thread Pool -- 37) WFLYSRV0010: Deployed "ojdbc7.jar" (runtime-name : "ojdbc7.jar")
wildfly2_1  | 08:37:16,122 INFO  [org.jboss.as.server] (ServerService Thread Pool -- 37) WFLYSRV0010: Deployed "mysql-connector-java-5.1.6.jar" (runtime-name : "mysql-connector-java-5.1.6.jar")
wildfly2_1  | 08:37:16,123 INFO  [org.jboss.as.server] (ServerService Thread Pool -- 37) WFLYSRV0010: Deployed "sqljdbc4.jar" (runtime-name : "sqljdbc4.jar")
wildfly2_1  | 08:37:16,188 INFO  [org.jboss.as.server] (Controller Boot Thread) WFLYSRV0212: Resuming server
wildfly2_1  | 08:37:16,193 INFO  [org.jboss.as] (Controller Boot Thread) WFLYSRV0060: Http management interface listening on http://127.0.0.1:9990/management
wildfly2_1  | 08:37:16,194 INFO  [org.jboss.as] (Controller Boot Thread) WFLYSRV0051: Admin console listening on http://127.0.0.1:9990
wildfly2_1  | 08:37:16,194 INFO  [org.jboss.as] (Controller Boot Thread) WFLYSRV0025: WildFly Full 11.0.0.Final (WildFly Core 3.0.8.Final) started in 5708ms - Started 458 of 688 services (357 services are lazy, passive or on-demand)
```

Comment: FYI: I made a workaround with changes in source code. I reported the issue (with "patch") here: https://issues.redhat.com/browse/WFLY-13808

Comment: FYI: I made an automated build of this patch on github (on a hacky way, because I couldn't reproduce the release build of wildfly) https://github.com/predkambrij/wildfly/releases/tag/refs%2Fheads%2Fgh_20.0.1.Final1599135914